# Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined when using custom build in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, flask, ckeditor5

I am building a Flask blog app and trying to integrate `CKEditor` in the templates. First, I tried implementing it using the `CDN` and it worked fine. Then I built a custom build using [CKEditor 5 Online Builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/). I downloaded the zip file, extracted it and put it inside my static folder in my flask project directory. I changed the script `src` that was previously linking to the `CDN` to my custom CKEditor build. After doing this, the page to create a new post works fine and it displays the ckeditor text area correctly. But the page to update an existing post shows the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined`.

My Folder Structure:

```
>flask_blog_1
    >main
        >__init__.py
        >routes.py
    >posts
        >__init__.py
        >forms.py
        >routes.py
    >static
        >ckeditor //Custom CKEditor5 Build
        >profile_pics
        >main.css
    >templates
        >...
        >create_post.html
        >layout.html
        >...
    >users
        >__init__.py
        >forms.py
        >routes.py
        >utils.py
    >__init__.py
    >config.py
    >models.py
    >instance
        >site.db
    >venv
    >.env
    >run.py
```

Below are the code of the files that I assume were the cause. If the code for any more files is required, please ask.

`posts/routes.py`:

```py
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, abort
from flaskblog import db
from flaskblog.posts.forms import PostForm
from flaskblog.models import Post
from flask_login import current_user, login_required

posts = Blueprint("posts", __name__)


@posts.route("/post/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(
            title=form.title.data,
            content=form.content.data,
            author=current_user,
        )
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your post has been created!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
    return render_template(
        "create_post.html", title="New Post", form=form, legend="New Post"
    )


@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, post=post)


@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.content = form.content.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your post has been updated.", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("posts.post", post_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.content.data = post.content
    return render_template(
        "create_post.html", title="Update Post", form=form, legend="Update Post"
    )


@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>/delete", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def delete_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Your post has been deleted.", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
```

The `new_post`, `post` and `delete_post` routes work just fine. The problem is only with the `update_post` route even though it renders the same `create_post.html` template just like the `new_post` route. Again, the ckeditor shows the `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined` error only in the `update_post` route. The ckeditor textarea also doesn't display in this route. But it works fine in the `new_post` route.

`templates/layout.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
    <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- ...................................ckeditor......................................... -->

    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.2/classic/ckeditor.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../static/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <!-- ...................................ckeditor end......................................... -->

</head>

<body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                    aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.home') }}">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.about') }}">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('posts.new_post') }}">New Post</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('users.account') }}">{{ current_user.username
                            }}</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('users.logout') }}">Logout</a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('users.login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('users.register') }}">Register</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
                    <p class='text-muted'>Put some information here.
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                    </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#content'))
            .then(editor => {
                editor.model.document.on('change', () => {
                    document.querySelector('#content-hidden').value = editor.getData();
                    console.log(editor.getData());
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code, right above the `</head>` tag, I have commented out the script tag for the CDN and written the script tag for the custom CKEditor build. When I comment out the second script tag and uncomment the first script tag, the update page works just fine.

`templates/create_post.html`:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.title.errors %}
                {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% else %}
                {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.content.errors %}
                <!-- {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", id="content") }} -->
                <div name="content" id="content" class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid">
                    {% if form.content.data %}
                    {{ form.content.data|safe }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content-hidden" />
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.content.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <!-- {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg", id="content") }} -->
                <div name="content" id="content" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    {% if form.content.data %}
                    {{ form.content.data|safe }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content-hidden" />
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my first time trying to use CKEditor. I have no idea why it works with cdn but not with custom build.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for my own future reference if I run into the same problem again.

So basically, when I was trying to create a new post, it was loading the `ckeditor.js` file from the correct place i.e. `flaskblog1/flaskblog/static/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js`. But when I was trying to update an existing post, it was trying to load the `ckeditor.js` file from `flaskblog1/flaskblog/posts/static/ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js` which it obviously did not find. That is why it was giving that error. I still have no idea why it did that though.

I solved the problem by using flask's `url_for` function which is available to use in the templates as well which I should have done from the start anyway. Basically, I changed my script tag to the following in `layout.html`:

```html
<!-- ...................................ckeditor......................................... -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<!-- ...................................ckeditor end......................................... -->
```